# How do I close all tabs containing a specific word in their title or URL using Vimperator?

Tags: firefox, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vimperator

Say I have many Firefox tabs open where some tabs have the same word in their title (eg. Stack), or some tabs point to different locations of a site (eg. keyword being stackoverflow in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/example1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/example2 etc.), and I want to close only these particular tabs using the Firefox extension Vimperator.

Does Vimperator have some existing key combination or command to do this using for example a string as input? If yes, how does it work? If no, how would a macro or other solution for this look like in Vimperator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The :bd (or :bdelete, for bufferdelete) takes a string as argument. So you can just use ":bd stack" and all "tabs" (Which are called buffers in the vim world) which are containing stack in the title, will be closed. This is revertable with the undo (u) command.